# Python Gui Crashing after 1 Hour

Tags: python, qt, logging

I have a python GUI written in PyQT5. It has a logging feature. When I run the gui and hit a button, it starts logging data every second. After 20 mins, my gui starts slowing down, and after 1 hour it crashes.

Interesting part is, this only happens if I run it through ".exe". If I run the GUI from pycharm, it does not crash even if I run the gui for 3 days.

```
    with open(file_path, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for key in initial_info.keys():
            csv_writer.writerow([key, initial_info[key]])

        csv_dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fields)
        csv_dict_writer.writeheader()
```

This is how I have done the logging. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue?

I created the .exe using Pyinstaller.
Crashing only occurs when I am logging, and it happens on every pc.
Wherever I save the .logfile the error occurs, it won't matter.
There is no difference in log file content between two ways of running the script.

Comment: What exactly does it mean that it "collapses"? Show error messages (if any) as properly formatted text in the question. Maybe create an exe which uses the console so it can simply print the errors.

Comment: There are no errors, it just collapses, and I can't press buttons anymore. I can't even move the GUI on screen from a point to another.

Comment: How do you create the .exe? Where is the log file saved (for .exe and running from IDE)? Does this "collapsing" also occur when you don't use the logging? Is there a difference in log file content between the two ways of running the script? So many questions that come to mind that might help find an answer. Please add as much relevant info to your question as possible.

Comment: @mahkitah I edited the question to include answers to your questions, thanks

Comment: What does your RAM utilisation look like? Maybe the logs are not properly being written to disk, but to RAM instead. This will make your program slow down when you start swapping, and be killed (on Linux, no idea what happens on other OS's) when you are out of swap space.

Comment: Maybe find another word for "collapse" because it doesn't mean anything in this context. Crash? Exit?

Comment: Huh?! Are you attempting to write then rewrite the same CSV file over and over again? Like you write 11 line CSV file. Then, loop again and you write a 12 line CSV file, etc? Of course, this is going to get worse. You should rework the logic to append to the end of the CSV file instead of rewriting lines you've rewritten before. It's approach you're going is possibly similar to that 12 days of Christmas song.

Comment: Post a [mre] with debugging details. Also you need to provide the PyInstaller options. Build the exe as a console application.(Ensure the file name of your main module does not have the '.pyw' extension, and don't use the '-w', '--windowed' and '--noconsole' options.) And run it in a console(cmd.exe).